# Is it possible to bind a command in WPF to the columnheader in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvmcross

I want to bind a sort command to a DataGridColumn.Header the functions works if it's bind to a button, but I want to implement it anyway in the columns header of the datagrid. I use MVVMCross as pattern so I should use a IMVXCommand to fire the function.

This is my XAML code in WPF if the "SortColumn"-button gets clicked nothing happens.

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="300" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <Button Content="SortColumn" Command="{Binding IMvxSortCommand}"/>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Names}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Thanks.

Read several discussions on Stackoverflow and tried different approaches.

Comment: is your xaml error view showing any binding issues?
what is it saying you can enable it under view->Toolbars->Xaml binding erros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, sorting in the UI is a simple sorting of the data presentation layer and not the original data. For this reason, the sorting must take place in the view (and not in the view model or model).

You can move the sorting algorithm to a custom [`IComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1.compare?view=net-8.0#returns) implementation or use the property based `ICollectionView.SortDescriptions` feature.

Even if you don't use MVVM, implementing the sort algorithm in a dedicated `IComparer<T>` implementation provides a very clean solution that doesn't pollute your data models with data view (UI) related sorting logic.
If you use MVVM this separation becomes mandatory.

This solution is also cleaner in terms of the UI click area of the column headers as it will preserve its default click behavior.
Because adding a `Button` as content of the column header won't disable the default click behavior which will cause weird behavior if the user clicks on the padded area around the `Button`!

**NameComparer.cs**

```cs
class NameComparer : IComparer<string>
{
  public int Compare(string firstName, secondName)
  {
    // TODO::Implement comparison rule:
    // return -1 when firstName < secondName
    //         0 when firstName == secondName
    //         1 when firstName > secondName
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void OnColumnSortingUsingIComparer(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
  {
    var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    
    bool isNameColumn = e.Column.Header is string columnName 
      && columnName.Equals("Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    if (!isNameColumn)
    {
      // Wrong column --> do not handle sorting of this column.
      // Continue and let the DataGrid use the default comparison for sorting.
      return;
    }

    // Cancel default sorting for this column
    e.Handled = true;

    ICollectionView dataGridDataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource);
    if (dataGridDataView is ListCollectionView listCollectionView)
    {            
      IComparer columnSortComparer = new NameComparer();
      listCollectionView.CustomSort = columnSortComparer;
    }
  }

  private void OnColumnSortingUsingSortDescription(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
  {
    var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;

    var sortDirection = e.Column.SortDirection;
    string propertyName = nameof(MyDatModel.SomeProperty);
    var columnSortDecsription = new SortDescription(propertyName, sortDirection);
    dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
    dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(columnSortDecsription);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <DataGrid Sorting="OnColumnSortingUsingSortDescription">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                          Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>

  <DataGrid Sorting="OnColumnSortingUsingIComparer">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                          Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

If for whatever reason you insist on adding a `Button` to attach an `ICommand` then you should define a `DataTemplate` for the `DataGridColumn.HeaderTemplate` property. This way you can continue to use the `DataGridColumn.Header` property independently:

```xml
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"                            
                        Binding="{Binding Name}">
      <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

          <!-- 
               The Command binding assumes that the command 'MySortCommand'   
               is defined in the DataContext of the DataGrid 
          -->
          <Button Content="{Binding}" 
                  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.MySortCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the detailed explanation, as a result I was able to improve my ViewModel by outsourcing a lot of the presentation layer code in the view.  Have a nice day!

Comment: If I want to restore the list order by the originally order. How can I implement this? Storing the list as a backup and replace the sorted list by it?

Comment: Which sorting method do you use? When you use SorDescriptions then simply clear the `ICollectionView.SortDescriptions` collection: `myDataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();`. If you use a custom `IComparer<T>` then simply set the `ListCollectionView.CustomSort` property to `null`: `((ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.ItemsSource)).CustomSort = null;`.

Comment: It's important to understand that both sorting methods only sort the data view of the underlying collection. The original collection remains unaffected by sorting. Same applies to filtering and grouping via the collection view. [Microsoft learn: Collection views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0#collection-views)

Comment: I figured out that it is normally enough to just click the header and the view gets sorted automatically, first ascending and then descending. This wasnt working for me in the first time because I used a style template for my list which disabled the clickable proberty, of my Column header. So I use now the default sort with a counter which gets incremented two times and then should the list appear in the originally order again. I tried several ways of clear set the sort to null but it just keeps switching between ascending and descending...

Comment: I see. I was wondering why the default sorting wasn't sufficient. I thought you had a very special sort rule. Your issue is not normal. Setting the CustomSort property to NULL must clear any sorting. Just make sure to set e.Handled=true ! Otherwise the DataGrid will execute the default sorting (instaed of no sort).

Comment: Complete code to clear the sorting from the `Sorting` event handler: `e.handled = true; ((ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource)).CustomSort = null;`

Comment: Note that this does not disable sorting. It just clears the override of the default sort behavior. To disable sorting either set `e.Handled = true;` and return from the handler or get the particular `DataGridColumn` and set the `DataGridColumn.CanUserSort` property to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The Header of a `DataGrid` is internally arranged with a `ItemsPresenter` and so each item will loose the `DataContext` of its parent.

You should always have a look at the [**XAML Binding Failures**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-data-binding-diagnostics?view=vs-2022) if get into such troubles.

Next step is to check the application with [SnoopWPF](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) where you can see the issue with the `ItemsPresenter`.

To get around this, you have to reset the DataContext or adjust the binding path like

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="theGrid">
 
    <!-- Option 1 -->

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="300" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <Button Content="SortColumn"
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=theGrid, Path=DataContext.IMvxSortCommand}"/>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Names}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    <!-- Option 2 -->

    <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="300" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=theGrid, Path=DataContext}">
                <Button Content="SortColumn"
                        Command="{Binding IMvxSortCommand}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Names}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```